# Wtforms QueryselectField doesn't pass id

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

- I have two tables in one-to-many relationship, table Project has many Reports.
- While the user entering a report issue, s/he will have to choose the project that this report belong to, from a drop-down list.
- The drop-down list shows the projects name but the add_report() stops at `db.session.commit()` and when I print the _form.project_list.data_, I get the *project name* instead of the foreign key.
- I believe my problem is in the forms, I tried many codes to get the project_id but I got the "unprintable InterfaceError object" error.
- **My Question:**
  How can I get the *project id* number instead of the project name from the drop-down list?

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/add_report/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_report():
    form = AddReportForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_report = Report(
                project_id=form.project_list.data,
                issue=form.issue.data)
            db.session.add(new_report)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('New report was successfully added.')
            return redirect(url_for('projects'))
        else:
            flash('All fields are required.')
            return redirect(url_for('projects'))
    return render_template('project.html', form=form)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Project(db.Model):
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    reports = db.relationship('Report', backref='project', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Report(db.Model):
    report_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.project_id'))
    issue = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.issue
```

**forms.py**

```
def get_projects():
    return Project.query

class AddReportForm(Form):
    project_list = QuerySelectField('Project', query_factory=get_projects)
    issue = StringField('issue')
```

*Thank you very much*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find what was wrong with my code :)

- I was using project_id(Foreign Key) in the report table to obtain the project id(form.project_list.data) instead of projects(relationship). So I made some changes in models.py and views.py.
  *Poor **forms.py**, I thought it was your fault!*

**models.py**

```
class Project(db.Model):
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Report(db.Model):
    report_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.project_id'))
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='report')
    issue = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.issue
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/add_report/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_report():
    form = AddReportForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_report = Report(
                projects=form.project_list.data,
                issue=form.issue.data)
            db.session.add(new_report)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('New report was successfully added.')
            return redirect(url_for('projects'))
        else:
            flash('All fields are required.')
            return redirect(url_for('projects'))
    return render_template('project.html', form=form)
```

**forms.py** stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Report table? do you mean the dropdown list? did you try

```
project_list = QuerySelectField('Project', query_factory=get_projects, get_label='project_id')
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254971/more-specific-sql-query-with-flask-wtf-queryselectfield) to reduce your query to only select the required columns.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
I tried *get_label='project_id'* and I got this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object>

Comment: Is the form showing up and the error happens on submit form?if so can you check your form.project_list.data by printing it before adding it to database and make sure you get the project_id? I thought your problem was on the form display,  you probably dont need get_label in QuerySelectField.

Comment: When debugging add_report() the function stops when it gets to `db.session.commit()`. When I print _form.project_list.data_, I get the project name like _Project 1_ instead of the foreign key!

Comment: Did you try QuerySelectField('Project', query_factory=get_projects, get_pk = 'project_id'). Although it should have automatically detected the primary key. Also inspect the dropdown element on the client side and see what value it has.

Comment: I just did but I got this error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
Also when debugging add_report() this time, it didn't pass the `if request.method == 'POST':`.

Comment: on which line did you get the str object is not callable error? can you post the error stack trace.

Comment: my bad, get_pk takes one argument callable.. it shouldn't be a string.

Comment: I used `get_pk = Project.project_id`, I got this error: TypeError: 'InstrumentedAttribute' object is not callable

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help, @bharani. Thank you

Comment: were you able to fix it? if so post the answer so that others can benefit as well.

Comment: get_pk=lambda p: p.project_id

Comment: No, I haven't fixed it yet, but I'm still working on it.
I have tried `get_pk=lambda p: p.project_id` yesterday but it didn't work, I get the same unprintable error.
I learned that `get_label=Project.project_id` will display the id number instead of the project name in the drop-down list.